# Making Calculator using JavaScript but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I decided to write a calculator but It doesn't work and I know it's correct it's not related to the code or maybe it is idk. but over 90% sure that the problem is not the code cause I wrote the same code on the internet.
I tried to write it in an external JS file so I wanted to paste it here like this that u won't get bothered.
thanks...

```js
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
function sum() {
    let num1 = document.querySelector('.num1');
    let num2 = document.querySelector('.num2');

    let num1 = parseInt(num1);
    let num2 = parseInt(num2);

    let submit = num1 + num2;

    result.textContent = submit;
}
```

```html
<label for="num1">Number 1 : </label>
<input type="number" class="num1" /><br><br>

<label for="num2">Number 2 : </label>
<input type="number" class="num2" /><br><br>

<input type="button" style="margin-left: 10px;" value="Submit" onclick="sum()"></button><br><br>

<label for="result">Result : </label>

<h1 class="result" />dd</h1>
```

Comment: I turned your code into a runnable snippet. As you see there *is* an error in your code. You cannot declare the same variable twice with `let`. If you would check the console, you would see that error.

Comment: Everything fixed. there was also another problem ``document.querySelector('.result').value;``
I see you are really professional you show me the way only with in sentence.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three issues in your code:

- `let` cannot be used twice for the same variable. That gives a parse error.
- There is no HTML element with `id` equal to "result". You should change `class="result"` to `id="result"`.
- The code tries to add HTML elements, but you should take the `value` property.

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result');
function sum() {
    let num1 = document.querySelector('.num1');
    let num2 = document.querySelector('.num2');
    num1 = parseInt(num1.value); // Take valeu!
    num2 = parseInt(num2.value);

    let submit = num1 + num2;

    result.innerHTML = submit;
}
```

```html
<label for="num1">Number 1 : </label>
<input type="number" class="num1" /><br><br>

<label for="num2">Number 2 : </label>
<input type="number" class="num2" /><br><br>

<input type="button" style="margin-left: 10px;" value="Submit" onclick="sum()"></button><br><br>

<label for="result">Result : </label>

<h1 id="result" />dd</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made changes to your code.

*Note:*
Do not declare the variable twice.
Also use **id** on input tags when you use label.

```js
function sum() {
    let result = document.getElementById('result');
    let num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    let num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;

    let num1Val = parseInt(num1);
    let num2Val = parseInt(num2);

    let submit = num1Val + num2Val;

    result.innerHTML = submit;
}
```

```html
<label for="num1">Number 1 : </label>
<input type="number" id="num1" /><br><br>

<label for="num2">Number 2 : </label>
<input type="number" id="num2" /><br><br>

<input type="button" style="margin-left: 10px;" value="Submit" onclick="sum()"><br>
<br>

<label for="result">Result : </label>
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

Reference

[id attribute usage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)

[class attribute usage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)

I recommend you to spend some time on learning basics.

[freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn)